# How to declare different state and props for subclasses on react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Super new to typescript and static type in general with React, so

Given that I have this parent component:

```
interface ParentProps {
 something: string
}

interface ParentState {
 somethingElse: string
}

export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentProps, ParentSate> {

  // Component Logic.

  sharedFunction() {
    // Some shared function.
  }
}
```

How can I declare different props and state on child component, for example:

```
interface ChildProps {
 something: string
}

interface ChildState {
 somethingElse: string
}

export default class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent<ChildProps, ChildState> {
  // Child component logic.
}
```

When I try the above I get:

```
[ts] Type 'ParentComponent' is not generic.
```

So, what is the best way of achieving this separation?, thanks.

Comment: In general it's not recommended you extend custom React components, it's advised you use composition rather than inheritance. There's info out there on why. Here's a page from the official React docs about replacing inheritance with composition: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Thank you @Jayce444 I have read the doc and I do believe thats the way I should approach my original problem on the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `ParentComponent` generic as well so that the `ChildComponent` can specify different props and state:

```
interface ParentProps {
    something: string
}

interface ParentState {
    somethingElse: string
}

export class ParentComponent<TProps extends ParentProps = ParentProps, TState extends ParentState = ParentState>
extends React.Component<TProps, TState> {

    // Component Logic.

    sharedFunction() {
        // Some shared function.
    }
}

interface ChildProps {
    something: string
}

interface ChildState {
    somethingElse: string
}

export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent<ChildProps, ChildState> {
    // Child component logic.
}
```